# How To Make A Dataframe From A Variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a code to print like this :

```
print('Logistic Regression')
print('Data Train :', logreg.score(X,y))
print('Data Test :', logreg.score(X_test,y_test))
print('KNN')
print('Data Train :', knn.score(X,y))
print('Data Test :', knn.score(X_test,y_test))
```

and the output is :

```
Logistic Regression

Data Train : 0.7171072127066912 

Data Test :
0.7219339324136186

KNN

Data Train : 0.9711521365495169

Data Test : 0.8530565751170738
```

how can i make it a dataframe like this :

|  | Logistic Regression | KNN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data Train | 0.7171072127066912 | 0.9711521365495169 |
| Data Test | 0.7219339324136186 | 0.8530565751170738 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that easily with list comprehension.

```
models = [logreg, knn]
model_names = ['Logistic Regression', 'KNN']
pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [model.score(a, b) for (a,b) in [(X, y), (X_test, y_test)]] 
            for model in models
    ], index=['Data Train', 'Data Test'], columns=model_names)
```

And when you want to include more models, you just update your `models` and `model_names` variables as;

```
models = [logreg, knn, dt, rf, xgb]
model_names = ['Logistic Regression', 'KNN', 'Decision Tree', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost']
```

And keep the latter part exactly the same.

Comment: thanks, work perfectly. but it can only have 2 variable, how to do it with more variable?
i tried :
pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [model.score(a, b, c, d, e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in [(X, y), (X_test, y_test)]] 
            for model in [logreg, knn, dt, rf, xgb]
    ], index=['Data Train', 'Data Test'], columns=['Logistic Regression', 'KNN', 'Decision Tree', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost'])

Comment: The idea is right, but I suppose you got a little lost in the definition. As you see in the answer I wrote, the individual models take the variable `model`. So, the inner list would not change, you just append the `model` variable. Let me update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only 2 models, you can use this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Logistic Regression":[logreg.score(X,y), logreg.score(X_test,y_test)], "KNN":[knn.score(X,y), knn.score(X_test,y_test)]}, index=['Data Train', 'Data Test'])
```